# Reusable components in Silex

Tags: symfony, silex

Is there any way to implement reusable components with Silex, in a similar way like symfony1 had components, and Symfony2 has subrequests? I basically want to capture the output of one or several reusable widgets (which have some logic in their controller) inside another controller.

I found a way to render Twig templates seperately, but I do have some components with an attached business logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you need:

> A render function is also register to help you render another controller from a template:

```
{{ render('/sidebar') }}

{# or if you are also using UrlGeneratorServiceProvider #}
{{ render(path('sidebar')) }}
```

Taken from [the Twig provider chapter](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html) of the documentation. Checking [the source](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/TwigCoreExtension.php#L31) also tells me it makes a subrequest.

Comment: Thank you, but I should also mention I want to capture the rendered output of one controller inside another. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do that, but the source code I linked should help you out.